# backgroundColor leaves black band at top of screen Xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a backgroundColor call that changes the UIView background color to white, but for some reason it leaves about a 20px bar at the top that remains black, could someone explain possibly? Thanks :).

```
- (void)setupSubviews {      
   self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
}
```

Comment: can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: and in what context is this being done? A `UIView` subclass or a `UIViewController` subclass?

Comment: @Jacob it's in a UIView subclass that is loaded into the viewController, and im not sure i can post a screenshot leme see about that.

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely that the you UIView does not cover the entire screen. You might of dropped the view in on interface builder when the window was set to have a status bar or navigation bar.

On interface Builder go to Size Inspector and make sure the view size is 320 x 480, or make sure your main view is set to have no status bar in Interface Builder (if you don't have one).